# pick list selection validation on vf page

Tags: picklist

I have a custom field pick list. when a particular picklist value is selected(on edit mode of a vf page) and save the page it show show up an error message, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic thing that you should be able to find via search, but here is goes. This works on standard Account field Rating.

> ispickVal(Rating, 'Hot')

or

> text(Rating) == 'Hot'

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this example.

```
if(PickList__c==Actual){
Value1= Integer.valueOf('x')
}
else if(PickList__c == 'Target'){
Value2 = Integer.valueOf('y')
```

Here what i am doing i habe a custom pick list in which there are two values names as value1 and value2 in which i am storing the integer value of the string x and y.